# Is Kafka A good option if we are looking for only one publisher

Tags: apache-kafka

Would it be a good idea to use Kafka publisher/subscriber architecture for an event service with one publisher only or should I go for custom socket event service?
What are the pros and cons that I should look for the comparison?

A brief about the problem-

I have an application which is emitting events and there will be 100 thousands of  subscribers, and I don't want that application to be overloaded with the subscriber requests so I want a layer in between the subscribers and the event publisher, which will serve the subscribers I am not clear with the fact, is KAFKA a good solution cause I have only one application that is emitting events and hence only one KAFKA producer,and how it is better from a custom socket pub-sub service.

Comment: I think you might want to say only one application ***for now*** :)

Answer (score 0):

The web is full of posts, blogs and commercial data articulating the benefits of message queueing (e.g. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q002630_.htm) 
Basically - decoupling is good concept in software engineering, so yeah - you should prefer use an independent pub-sub mechanism, and not manage the subscribers in your application, be it Kafka, or RabbitMQ, or any other solution that suit your needs. Kafka is nearly industry standard, and probably best of breed for most use cases.